# How to change the heading for \tableofcontents in Latex?

Tags: format, latex, tableofcontents, xelatex

I've been trying to change the layout of my \tableofcontents in Latex for a while now and I can't find a solution. So the problem is, I have some chapters added before the table of contents. I managed to disable all headings for the frontmatter, but now the title of the last chapter is being shown.

I'm using the `scrbook` environment and nothing really seems to work. This is how I create my frontmatter in a seperate `toc_lof_lot_lol.tex` file.

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Pseudocodeverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Quelltextverzeichnis}

\tableofcontents   

\listoffigures\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage} 
\listoftables\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage} 
\lstlistoflistings\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage} 

\setcounter{page}{1}
```

This is the content before the table of contents in `01_0_fundamental_stuff_root.tex`

```
\chapter{Liste der Abkürzungen}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{A} - Text A
    \item \textbf{B} - Text B
    \item \textbf{V} - Text C
\end{itemize}
\clearpage
```

And this is my document structure

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
    \include{chapters/00_title/00_title}       
    \include{chapters/01_fundamental_stuff/01_0_fundamental_stuff_root}
    \include{sources/toc_lof_lot_lol}      
\mainmatter
    \doublespacing
    \include{...}      
    ...
\backmatter
    \singlespacing
    ...
\end{document}
```

My Table of contents looks like this right now, but I either want to change the text in the heading to "Inhaltsverzeichnis" or simply delete the text in the heading completely

[image: Table of Contents]

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to create an invisible chapter before the table of contents, so the text in the heading changed to "Inhaltsverzeichnis"

I added this command before the beginning of the document

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Then I changed the \tableofcontents command in the `toc_lof_lot_lol.tex`

```
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\unchapter{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
  \oldtableofcontents%
}
\makeatother 

\tableofcontents
```

Definitely not the correct way to go, but solved my problem.